# How can we add popover on gantt highchart

Tags: highcharts, gantt-chart, highcharts-gantt

[image]

I am using gantt highcharts in my angular application. In Gantt highcharts, I need to add popover on a click of icon on parent row.

I am fairly new to this.
Please help!
Thanks

Comment: Have you already implemented this button? Could you please share your code in some online code editor?

Comment: Hy @KarolKołodziej,
Thanks for the reply. here is my JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hr260389/cy4z637k/5/ .
you can see the three dot icon . need to open popover on that click.

Comment: This example could be useful [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/13h8v2bd/), inside events render you add event click. You catch this element, now you need to create a popup, CSS will be ok for this.